# MySQL string and concat

Tags: mysql

So I want to take the first letter of the first name and all of the last name, add them together and make that the person's username.

I was using CONCAT() and I keep getting an unexplained syntax error from MySQL.

I have:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(left(first_name, 1), left(last_name)) username
FROM survey_responders;
```

And all I get is "Syntax Error" as my error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't LEFT require two parameters?  What happens when you use left (last_name,1) instead of left(last_name)?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the second argument for left(last_name), but I don't even think you need that call to left since you want the whole thing. So:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(left(first_name, 1), last_name) username
FROM survey_responders;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function left is good but substr is more efficient, try this instead:

`select concat(substr(first_name, 1, 1), last_name) username 
FROM survey_responders;`